# Angular 7 won't start navigation, no errors are seen. Any tips on what's wrong?

Tags: angular, routes, zone

I have an Angular 7 application where I navigate to a link e.g. eligibility/1, it works no problem and the network tab shows the outbound request. After the page renders, attempts to navigate to eligibility/2 (via a link click) won't send outbound request.

The router trace shows this:

[image: Router Trace]

This is the Javascript after the router navigate call.  Note the promise being returned to temp shows a zone state of Null and Value of Array(0).

Is this a zone issue? Note there are no Console errors either.

[image: After Navigate Call]

Comment: For 'outbound request' you mean a call to the API backend? If yes, can you post the code you are using to perform the call?

Comment: See line two in code shot above (2nd picture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular, by default will not refresh an already loaded component. But that behavior can be overridden as shown here.

```
 // Browser is already on /pathName/5102 
 // We see the proper display which means
 // our router paths are correct.
 // And now we attempt to go to a new path.

 let newLocation = `/pathName/5110`;
 // override default re use strategy
 this.router
    .routeReuseStrategy
    .shouldReuseRoute = function () {
        return false;
 };
 this.router
   .navigateByUrl(newLocation)
   .then(
   (worked) => {
     // Works only because we hooked
     // routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute 
     // and explicitly told it don't reuse
     // route which forces a reload.
     // Otherwise; the url will change but new
     // data will not display!
   },
   (error) => {
    debugger;
    }
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to refresh the page when navigating to the same Url, you must configure the **RouterModule** this way:

```
@ngModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’})],
 exports: [RouterModule],
 })
```

This will change the whole behaviour in your application, so probably is better to subscribe to the **params** observable of the **ActivatedRoute**:

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
  console.log(params);
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.data);
});
```

Comment: Just to expand on this a little bit, a component is not destroyed and then reinitialised when a route parameter changes, which is why you're not getting a new HTTP request. The correct approach as Martino points out is subscribing to the route params observable and triggering the HTTP request from there.

Answer (score 1):

If there's only outgoing calls going on in your component initialization, I wouldn't expect there to be anything in the network tab. Angular applications are SPAs and the component that is handling your `eligibility` url is most likely only being created once and then loaded from memory at each following navigation until destroyed. So, if you want some behavior done at each navigation, you'll have to subscribe to the navigation events and do your work there.

I have a simple [routing example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vatisc) that sounds like it behaves similarly to what you are describing. Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: That confirms the behavior, the page is "cached" so to speak.  This may explain why using Window.Open seemed to work.  I'll confirm and post back.